# contentBinding two selectboxes in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am having trouble binding one selectbox to another. I would like for the options in one selectbox to depend on what is selected in the other. In this situation I would like to for the content of the second selectbox to populate according to what is selected in the first. I'm pretty new to Ember so I am looking for some guidance on what approach to take. I have tried using computed properties, but that wasn't successful. Do I need to use an observer to monitor for changes in the first select box?

## view

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="lookup">

<h1 style="padding: 0; margin: 0 0 15px 0;"> Lookup </h1> 

<label for="DEName">Data Extension</label>
{{view "select" contentBinding='content' id="DEName" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.name" selectionBinding=lookupDE}}

<div class='multi_column_section'> 
    <div class='inlineInput'> 
        <label class='inlineLabel' for='filter_column'>Filter Column </label> 
        {{view "select"  contentBinding=adjustFilter}}
    </div> <!-- 
    --><div class='inlineInput'> &nbsp; = &nbsp; </div> <!-- 
    --> <div class='inlineInput'> 
            <label class='inlineLabel' for='filter_value'>Filter Value </label> 
            <input type='text' class='nj_textBox' id='filter_value' name='filter_value'> 
        </div> 
</div>

<a href="#" {{action 'formString'}} class="generate_btn">Generate</a>

</script>
#Lookup Controller
App.LookupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

content:[
    {
        name: "Customers", fields:["first_name", "last_name", "address", "email"]
    }, 
    {
        name: "Products", fields:["sku", "name"]
    }, 
    {
        name:"Sales", fields:["product_sku", "sales_rep", "customer_id", "transaction_id", "date"]
    }
],  
lookupDE:"Sales", 
adjustFilter: function(){
    var myContent = this.get("content"); 
    for(i=0; i<myContent.length; i++){
        if(myContent[i].name == this.lookupDE){
            return myContent[i].fields; 
        }
    }
    
        console.log(this.lookupDE);
        // console.log(this.names[i].name); 
    
    //return ["first_name", "last_name", "address", "email"];
}.property(), 
actions: {
formString: function(){
    //console.log(this.lookupDE); 
    var outputString = '%%[Lookup("'+this.lookupDE+'")]%%';
    $("#output").text(outputString);    
}
```

},
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy in Ember. Conceptually you create a computed property for the data of the second select box which depends on the selection of the first one. This can be done with the `.property('selectionOfFirstSelect')` notation to create a computed, dependent property.

And here is an implementation that you might want to check:

https://gist.github.com/dgroch/11126341